# eslint-plugin-jest gives "ESLint stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, eslint

When adding the `jest` plugin to `.eslintrc.js`, I get the following stack error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined`

1. Create new react native project using `react-native` CLI
2. Install eslint and run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`
3. Install eslint-plugin-jest
4. Add `jest` to the plugin array in `.eslintrc.js`

### .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: ["standard", "plugin:jest/recommended"],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  plugins: ["react", "jest"],
  rules: {}
};
```

I expect that eslint picks up the eslint-plugin-jest plugin, but instead I get

```
[Error - 18:38:16] ESLint stack trace:
[Error - 18:38:16] TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined
    at c.isFunction.H.handled.has.p.getRules.forEach (/home/bob/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.0/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:55431)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/bob/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.0/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:55413
    at W.E.get.N.then.n (/home/bob/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.0/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:55555)
```

Comment: https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/issues/268

Comment: Issue raised on their github issues list. Someone suggested downgrading to 22.5.1 but while that solves the problem, more issues arise with the location of eslint-plugin-jest/lib/index.js. Still no solution at the moment.

Comment: Still, we can't help you fix problems in third party code, that's what their issue tracker is for.

Comment: Yeah, understood. Left the message here for anyone else who finds this page. Package maintainers are aware of the issue and plan to release an update later today I think.

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary issue in 22.6 up to 22.6.2. It has now been fixed in 22.6.3 released today. Just need to update the package.