# eslint-config-react-app/jest': Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined

Tags: docker, jestjs, create-react-app

I create a project with create-react-app. I get this error when i run `docker build frontend -t my-frontend .` :

```
> frontend@0.1.0 build /app
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest': Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-27T11_11_23_140Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

how should i fix it? i tried `npm install`,`npm install .`,`npm audit fix`.

this is jest in my `package.json` :

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    ...,
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

and this is jest in my `package.lock.json` :

```
"eslint-plugin-jest": {
      "version": "24.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-plugin-jest/-/eslint-plugin-jest-24.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "...",
      "requires": {
        "@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils": "^4.0.1"
      }
    },
```

I also saw [eslint-plugin-jest gives "ESLint stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'meta' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262332/eslint-plugin-jest-gives-eslint-stack-trace-typeerror-cannot-read-property-m) that says: " This was a temporary issue in 22.6 up to 22.6.2" but my version is 24.1.3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by `npm audit fix --force` but before run, make sure it does not damage your project.

> npm audit fix only modifies the dependencies that shouldn't cause problems based on SEMVER rules. The --force is a dangerious option because it upgrades the dependencies regardless of any rules. This can cause a dependency to go from version 1.2. 0 to version 2.3.

[What did a npm audit fix --force change and how do you fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030285/what-did-a-npm-audit-fix-force-change-and-how-do-you-fix-it)